# Recurrence relation limit outside range of values

Tags: real-analysis, limits, recurrence-relations

I Have a recurrence relation defined by:

- $a_1=0$
- $a_{n+1}=\frac{3a_n+1}{a_n+3}$
- $0\leq a_n \lt 1$

When trying to find the limit of this by n$\rightarrow\infty$ and using algebra of limits i get:

$l=\frac{3l+1}{l+3}$

$l^2+3l=3l+1$

$l=\pm1$

Now since $0\leq a_n \lt 1$ the limit can not be -1, but it also appears to not be 1.

Can anyone help me determine if the limit is 1 or something else?

Comment: Your approach seems right. Why do you think the limit is not $1$?

Comment: What is the limit of $1 - \left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$ which is a sequence of numbers all strictly less than $1$?

Comment: Because $a_n \lt 1$, or because we are taking a limit this means that fact does not matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because a sequence is bounded strictly, does not prevent its limit from being equal to that bound.

For example $x_n=\frac{1}{n} > 0$ for all $n$ yet $x_n \to 0$

In general if $a<x_n<b$ and $x_n \to x$ then all we can deduce is $a \le x \le b$.

Comment: Okay thanks! For some reason i could not justify it to myself but you are right.